# mysql_real_escape_string error

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm getting `Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Here's my code..

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);

$validation = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if ( $validation ) {
    // Make a MySQL Connection
    mysql_connect($Host,$Username,$Password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($Database) or die(mysql_error());

    // Insert rows
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO formusers
    (formemail) VALUES('$email') ") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 
}
?>
```

It does work if I move the lines to make a database connection up. Is it necessary to make a database connection before using `mysql_real_escape_string` or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do need an open mysql connection in order to do that.

I recommend you put the mysql_connect() on top of the script to make sure this error will never occur. (of course, it can still happen if you connect wrongly to the database)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is required.

> Note:
>
> A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string() otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is
>   generated, and FALSE is returned. If link_identifier isn't defined,
>   the last MySQL connection is used.

[http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php](http://mysql_real_escape_string%20Doc)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't establish a mysql connection you can use:

[mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php)

BUT: It's DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0!

Always use `mysql_real_escape_string` if possible!